# Is adding conceptual sub-units to a model to deal with repeated measurements appropriate?

Tags: r, mixed-model, repeated-measures, experiment-design, nested-data

I've been contemplating this question by @user7937045  ([Permutation test - can I apply it here?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/489698/permutation-test-can-i-apply-it-here)).  The linked question is regarding whether or not it's ok, or even preferred, to use a permutation-based approach in the analysis, but my question is about how to structure this kind of model without even looking at permutation.  So, for my question I'll assume functions like lm, aov, lmer, etc are appropriate.

After some discussion with the author, the Size factor can be considered a continuous numeric variable instead of ordered categorical, so I will use that in my question as well.

I wasn't aware until most recently, but a version of the question was asked previously at the following link:
[Repeated measurements with different measurement methods and uneven sample size - which test is suited?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/458337/repeated-measurements-with-different-measurement-methods-and-uneven-sample-size)

For that second link, user carlo gave an answer, and I think I disagree.  I put it that way because it could easily be the case that I just have different assumptions about the data generating process.  Or, I could just simply be wrong. carlo is certainly more of a statistical expert than I am (self taught, never studied any mathematical statistics) and perhaps sees something that I miss.

So, for my question, here is what a typical simulated dataset looks like, with 3 Vertebra, 3 Modalities, and 5 Size (numeric) treatment levels and with 2 measurements (Repeats) for each combination of those three variables.

```
> str(my.df)
'data.frame':   90 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Vertebra: Factor w/ 3 levels "L1","L2","L3": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Modality: Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Size    : num  1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 ...
 $ Repeats : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 ...
 $ Resp    : num  -0.622 -0.401 0.814 0.745 0.116 ...

> head(my.df, n=22)
   Vertebra Modality Size Repeats       Resp
1        L1        A    1       1 -0.6218196
2        L1        A    1       2 -0.4008962
3        L1        A    2       1  0.8142930
4        L1        A    2       2  0.7448103
5        L1        A    3       1  0.1155250
6        L1        A    3       2  0.1043017
7        L1        A    4       1  3.8555043
8        L1        A    4       2  3.8689745
9        L1        A    5       1  0.8936528
10       L1        A    5       2  0.8189421
11       L1        B    1       1  2.4238512
12       L1        B    1       2  2.5249164
13       L1        B    2       1  3.9524340
14       L1        B    2       2  3.6915641
15       L1        B    3       1  3.6278283
16       L1        B    3       2  3.5223896
17       L1        B    4       1  3.2962440
18       L1        B    4       2  3.2733177
19       L1        B    5       1  5.1127607
20       L1        B    5       2  4.9992031
21       L1        C    1       1  2.9859254
22       L1        C    1       2  3.1085032
```

The fundamental issue that I see is that the two repeated measurements at each combination of Vertebra, Modality, and Size, are treated as replicates rather than repeats, according to this formula:

`m_complete= lm(DB~Modality*Size+Vertebra, data= df)`

I've put together some R code that will create a data frame with the appropriate factor and data structure:

```
# assign how many factor levels for each factor
N_Vertebra <- 3  ### if changed, will need to change code in the creation of df()
N_Modality <- 3  ### if changed, will need to change code in the creation of df()
N_Size <- 5  # five fat rings
N_reps <- 200  # how many measurements at each combination of Vertebra, Modality, and Size?
total_N <-  N_Vertebra * N_Modality * N_Size * N_reps

unit_sd <- 1  # how much process noise, excluding the noise from the measurement system itself
repeat_sd <- 0.1  # the measurement-to-measurement noise

# Putting together the dataframe of the factors first
my.df <- data.frame(
  Vertebra = factor(rep( x=c("L1","L2","L3"), each=N_reps*N_Size*N_Modality, times = 1)) ,
  Modality = factor(rep( x = c("A","B","C"), each=N_reps*N_Size, times=total_N/(N_reps*N_Size*N_Modality))) ,
  Size = as.numeric(rep( x=1:N_Size, each=N_reps, times=total_N/(N_reps*N_Size))) ,
  Repeats = factor(rep( x=1:N_reps, each=1, times=total_N/N_reps ))
)

# can change the scale of any of the effects here, but no interaction
Modality_effect <- as.numeric(my.df$Modality) * 1
Vertebra_effect <- as.numeric(my.df$Vertebra) * 0
Size_effect <- my.df$Size * 0.3

# some, no doubt cludgy, code to assign noise at the level above the repeated measurements
tbl_unit_sd <- rnorm(total_N/N_reps, 0, unit_sd)
unit_noise <- rep(x = tbl_unit_sd, each=N_reps, times=1)

# now, to make the repeated measurements of the same thing slightly different, add measurement noise
repeat_noise <- rnorm(n = total_N, mean=0, sd=repeat_sd)

# create the response variable and store it in the dataframe
Resp <- Modality_effect + Vertebra_effect + Size_effect + unit_noise + repeat_noise
my.df$Resp <- Resp

mod.lm.interaction <- lm(Resp ~ Vertebra + Modality*Size, data=my.df)
summary(mod.lm.interaction)

# Call:
#   lm(formula = Resp ~ Vertebra + Modality * Size, data = my.df)
# 
# Residuals:
#   Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
# -1.68310 -0.90366  0.01449  0.68929  2.14039 
# 
# Coefficients:
#                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)      0.3602     0.4897   0.736  0.46410    
# VertebraL2       0.1425     0.2789   0.511  0.61066    
# VertebraL3       0.1100     0.2789   0.394  0.69432    
# ModalityB        2.1205     0.6540   3.242  0.00171 ** 
# ModalityC        2.6804     0.6540   4.098 9.72e-05 ***
# Size             0.4431     0.1394   3.178  0.00209 ** 
# ModalityB:Size  -0.3796     0.1972  -1.925  0.05769 .  
# ModalityC:Size  -0.1726     0.1972  -0.875  0.38389    
# ---
#   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# Residual standard error: 1.08 on 82 degrees of freedom
# Multiple R-squared:  0.4766,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.4319 
# F-statistic: 10.67 on 7 and 82 DF,  p-value: 1.788e-09
```

You can see that the t-values for Modality are about 3 or 4.  However, if I change the number of repeats (N_reps) from 2 to 200, the t-values go up to about 70.  The upshot is that we could skyrocket our power by just measuring our samples over and over, like measuring the weight of a person many times by having them step on and off the scale repeatedly, and that just seems wrong to me.

I've been wrestling with this problem, and I think I've come up with a solution.  My proposed solution is to add *conceptual* sub-units to the model. If this were a typical experiment, say like an agricultural experiment where the application of treatments was destructive, you'd have physical sub-units (e.g. plots within a field) to which treatments would be applied.  By including the sub-units as random factors in the model, variability between these sub-units within identical treatment conditions would be the variability against which the variability between treatments would be evaluated.  You could have 2000 repeated measurements per treatment, and it wouldn't increase the degrees of freedom at the inappropriate stratum.

In the Vertebra example there are no physical sub-units, which is what confused me so much. Ok, so if that's the case, then exactly what are the treatments being applied to?  They are being applied to the Vertebra, but at different points in time.  I'm conceptualizing these as sub-units.  So, I will now have sub-units to include in the model, even if they are not physical.  Here is how I would implement an analysis, adding this onto the end of the previous code:

```
my.df$subunit <- as.factor(rep(1:(N_Vertebra*N_Modality*N_Size), each=N_reps, times=1))

library(lme4)
mod.lmer <- lmer(Resp ~ Vertebra + Modality*Size + (1|subunit), data=my.df)
summary(mod.lmer)
```

Running that with N_reps=2 and N_reps=200 shows that the t-values don't inflate as the number of repeats goes up.

So, my questions:

1. Do you agree that the approach using conceptual sub-units and the lmer() model as stated is appropriate?  If so, do you know of any good reading materials (books, papers, websites) that explain this issue in greater depth?  I knew enough to put this together, but I would not say that I have a firm grasp of everything going on.  Even without the creation of conceptual sub-units, reading materials would be appreciated.
2. If the number of repeated measurements was not the same for all treatments, such as N_reps=2 for Modality A, and N_reps=3 for Modalities B and C, such as what user7937045's questions have, lmer() appropriately accounts for this, right?

I don't know how to add a notification to user7937045 or carlo, but since I reference their previous questions/answers, I'd like to, for the sake of courtesy.  Is that possible?

Comment: What is your research question ? What is the purpose of the model ?

Comment: Well, user7937045's stated research question is "assess the impact of Modality and Size on BD" as found in the first link.  Personally I'd probably use rstanarm::stan_lmer() with either the default regularizing priors or some informative priors, but what _I_ am most interested in is how to deal with the apparent pseudo replication, and for that I'll just stick with the classical frequentist tools.

Comment: To notify a user try to prepend their user  name with @